# What is the best way to use using?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, using

What is the best way to use using?

code1:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployeePicture(string userId)
{
    using IClubRep current = new ClubRep(_db);
    var data = await current.CurrentUserData(user.Id);
}
```

code2:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployeePicture(string userId)
{
    using (IClubRep current = new ClubRep(_db))
    {
        var data = await current.CurrentUserData(user.Id);
    }
}
```

code3:

```
private IClubRep Club { get; set; }
.
.
.
public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployeePicture(string userId)
{
    Club = new ClubRep(_db);
    var data = await Club.CurrentUserData(user.Id);
}
```

What do you think is the best way to use using?
The least pressure on the system.

Comment: `code1` and `code2` compile to exactly the same IL. Use whatever is preferable to you and your team. `code3` fails to dispose of `ClubRep` and should not be used (assuming `IClubRep` is indeed `IDisposable`, otherwise `code1` and `code2` won't compile). On every call to `EditEmployeePicture`, a new instance would be leaked. Even if it was reused somehow, it's not clear who should be disposing. In general, you want to keep the scope of disposable objects as small as possible.

Comment: Code 1 and Code 2 are the same. Code 3 does not call `Dispose()`.

Comment: With code 2 you have control of when the object is being disposed of. Preferred imo.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `code1` and `code2` ***are not*** exactly the same. Disposal happens on the same line in `code1` (rendering it somewhat pointless), but after the code block in `code2`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZBcz36

Comment: @spender: your supposed example is incorrect and doesn't demonstrate the scenario in the question. [`using` declarations (introduced in C# 8)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration) are not the same thing as a single-line `using` expression. A value introduced with a `using` declaration will be disposed at the end of the variable's scope, which in this case is the end of  the method (that is, the same as `code2`).

Comment: OTOH c# 8 is not explictily specified in the question (as it should be) but can only be inferred..

Comment: @TaW: OTOH the code wouldn't legally compile in earlier versions of C# since that syntax isn't supported, so it's not a big leap to assume. :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oops. You live & learn. I've been away from C# for quite a while now.

Answer (score 2):

With code1: your disposable lives until the end of the method because the compiler-generated try/catch/finally block encompasses all the code. With code2: it only lives to the until the end of the `using` block because the compiler generates a separate try/catch/finally for that section.

In your example they are exactly the same, but if you had a significant amount of code after this: `using IClubRep current = new ClubRep(_db);`, then the disposable would live slightly longer.

Comment: Code 1 disposes the moment the semi-colon at the end of the line is reached (and causes a compiler warning). When we reach the next line, the object is already disposed. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZBcz36

Comment: @spender your example is not a proper analog to the OP's example. You do not use the disposable after the using statement. [See this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lGs3j8)